# How to create Jms EventBuilder and Event formatter for WSO2CEP with admin services?

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-cep

I tried finding examples in the [integration test samples](https://github.com/wso2-dev/product-cep/) but I couldn't find any. I found something for the builder that was commented but apparently its `wsdl` has changed and was not usable.

This [sample](https://github.com/wso2-dev/product-cep/blob/master/modules/integration/tests-common/integration-test-utils/src/main/java/org/wso2/cep/integration/common/utils/ConfigurationUtil.java) has

> public void configureForJms(EventBuilderConfigurationDto eventBuilderConfigurationDto, String topic) throws RemoteException {...}

which is the thing that I need, but it is commented and when I uncomment it, doesn't work.

Does anyone have samples?

`Note` I use WSO2 Message Broker and WSOCEP 3.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

First Go to `${CEP_HOME}/repository/conf/carbon.xml` and search for `HideAdminServiceWSDLs` xml tag and make it false and restart the server. After the server started up, you can find the wsdl for event builder admin service on,

https://server_ip:port/services/EventBuilderAdminService?wsdl
(e.g. https://172.20.10.9:9443/services/EventBuilderAdminService?wsdl)

And event formatter on https://server_ip:port/services/EventFormatterAdminService?wsdl
(e.g. https://172.20.10.9:9443/services/EventFormatterAdminService?wsdl)

Use some tool like soapui and use the above wsdls to create the web service projects and simply hit the service.

Comment: I have done all you mentioned.I need sample codes for what I asked in the question. I need an exact code sample.

Comment: Goto ${CEP_HOME}/samples/artifacts there you can find the complete samples

Comment: I also cannot find already written samples for the thing you're mentioned. But, by using ${CEP_HOME}/samples/artifacts and admin services, it is easy to write a simple sample, since, it is nothing more than sending a soap message to the mentioned endpoints :)